# Unit Testing Android app that relies on Robolectric / RxJava / RxAndroid

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, retrofit, rx-android

I am using the Robolectric 3.0 snapshot.

I have a test:

```java
@Test
public void my_test() throws Exception {
        when(testReferenceManager.getUserServiceMock().checkUsernameAvailability(anyString())).thenReturn(Observable.just(Arrays.asList(new User("test@email.com", "password"))));
        when(testReferenceManager.getUserServiceMock().checkAuthStatus(anyString())).thenReturn(Observable.just(Arrays.asList(new User("test@email.com", "password"))));

        EditText emailText = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.text_email);
        EditText passwordText = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.text_password);
        Button signInButton = (Button)activity.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);


        emailText.setText("test@email.com");
        passwordText.setText("password");

        Robolectric.flushBackgroundScheduler();
        Robolectric.flushForegroundScheduler();    

        assertThat(signInButton.getText()).isEqualTo(App.R.getString(R.string.button_login));
}
```

The key thing here is that if the API reports a user exists (which it does from the mocks above) the sign in button text should be the same as the value of the string resource named `R.string.button_login`.

The setup for changing the button state is done in my Activity like this:

```java
        ReactiveEditText.textObservableForTextView(emailText)
            .startWith(emailText.getText().toString())
            .switchMap(new Func1<String, Observable<Boolean>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Boolean> call(String username) {
                    return webServices.usernameAvailable(username);
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new EndlessObserver<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(Boolean available) {
                    if (available) {
                        signInButton.setText(getString(R.string.button_signup));
                    } else {
                        signInButton.setText(getString(R.string.button_login));
                    }
                }
            });
```

ReactiveEditText.textObservableForTextView simply wraps the textChangedListener interface in a reactive fashion:

```java
public static Observable<String> textObservableForTextView(final TextView tv) {
        Observable<String> textObservable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                tv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
                    @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        subscriber.onNext(s.toString());
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return ViewObservable.bindView(tv, textObservable);
}
```

usernameAvailable receives the mocked data above and looks like this:

```
    // If the incoming array is size 0 the username is available, otherwise it already exists. 

public Observable<Boolean> usernameAvailable(final String username) {
    return userService.checkUsernameAvailability(username)
            .map(new Func1<List<User>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(List<User> usersMatchingUsername) {
                    return usersMatchingUsername.size() == 0;
                }
            });
}
```

Notice that I am using the 'immediate' scheduler to listen for changes to the EditText. My confusion is this: the unit test always fails, and it seems to me (when I jump into the debugger) that the `assertThat` statement in the test is firing before the observer ever sees a change in the EditText. I do see in the debugger that the Observer does eventually fire and the text is properly set on the signInButton. I thought using the immediate scheduler would make everything happen as I expect directly after `setText` is called.

Comment: If I add Thread.sleep(4000) after the last setText in my test it passes. Also if I return Observable.just(true); in usernameAvailable it passes.

Comment: Looks like you have asynchrone execution somewhere. With robolectric all should be synchron to avoid tests with sleep. How do you create async jobs? Perhaps your style is not covered by robolectric.

Comment: I use Retrofit to do async requests, though I mock the responses (the relevant mock in this case being the first line of the test). I do think you're right - it's clearly an async issue. I thought calling flushBackground/flushForeground would give the system time to finish the request and then update the main thread before the test would move on.

Comment: I have no experience with retrofit. But I had the same issue with androidannotations. The solution was to shadow the class which executes the async tasks on a different thread and execute them with robolectric. here my androidannotations example: https://github.com/nenick/AndroidAppDevelopment/blob/master/TestSupportRobolectric/src/main/java/com/example/robolectric/support/ShadowBackgroundExecutor.java

Answer (score 2):

Add following before asserting. It works for me.

```
    // Flush all worker tasks out of queue and force them to execute.
    Robolectric.flushBackgroundThreadScheduler();
    Robolectric.getBackgroundThreadScheduler().idleConstantly(true);

    // A latch used to lock UI Thread.
    final CountDownLatch lock = new CountDownLatch(1);

    try
    {
        lock.await(millisecond, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        lock.notifyAll();
    }

    // Flush all UI tasks out of queue and force them to execute.
    Robolectric.flushForegroundThreadScheduler();
    Robolectric.getForegroundThreadScheduler().idleConstantly(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue with Observables. The way I got around is to use

```
usernameAvailable("username").toBlocking().first();
```

This will give you the first result of the observable, synchronously in the test.

Comment: The reason I can't do this directly is the tests don't really know or care about the observables, that code is called from my Activity.

Comment: @WoogieNoogie Did you try using the immediate scheduler instead?

Comment: We did try both the immediate and test schedulers, but in both cases, the test finished without actually going into the Observable.

Comment: Looks like this will solve our problems: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/pull/135 <3 RxAndroid

Comment: @powerj1984, could you please elaborate your answer a bit more? I'm new to RxJava and I'm trying to do the same, but it seems painful.